# Plotting added-variable plots for linear and non-linear multiple regression lines

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, linear-regression, non-linear-regression

I want to plot the results of a multiple regression model that contains linear and non-linear relationships. I want one plot for each predictor, conditional on the other predictors.

Here is my example data:

```
library(car)
library(broom)
library(jtools)


## fit model: 
model <- lm(mpg ~ poly(disp,3) + wt + carb + factor(gear), data = mtcars)
summary(model)
```

The function "avPlots" creates added-variable plots, which are a good starting point:

```
avPlots(model)
```

**Is there a way to produce single added-variable plots for each predictor (similar to avPlots), that also plots curvlinear relationships? Possibly a solution with ggplot?**

My solution was this, but this does not seem to work:

```
sub <- augment(model, mtcars) # use augment from broom to get fitted values
plot(sub$wt, sub$.fitted) # 
abline(sub$.fitted, sub$wt, col="blue", lwd=3)
```

The regression line does not fit the points. Also, this does not allow to plot non-linear relationships.

Similarly, "effect_plot" plots single added-variable plots. However, this works only without polynomial relationships:

```
model <- lm(mpg ~  wt + carb + factor(gear), data = mtcars) # model without poly
summary(model)
effect_plot(model, pred=wt, plot.points = TRUE)
```

Thanks for your help!!!